# Add string if the pattern matched using Regtex

Tags: r, regex

I have a data table and I want to add a string (FirstWord!) to one column values if the pattern (Letter digits:Letter(s)digits) matches is like below

```
ColName
New test defiend
G54:Y23 (matched)
test:New
```

The expected results would be

```
New test defiend
FirstWord!G54:Y23
test:New
```

dt[, ColName := ColName %>% str_replace('(?<=\d)\:(?=[[:upper:]])',
paste0("'FirstWord!'",.))]

I don't know how to add the "FristWord!" when I find the pattern in the ColName.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(df, ColName = sub("([A-Z][0-9]+:[A-Z]+[0-9]+)", 'FirstWord!\\1', ColName))
            ColName
1  New test defiend
2 FirstWord!G54:Y23
3          test:New
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub` and backreference:

```
sub("([A-Z]+\\d+:[A-Z]+)", "FirstWord!\\1", txt)
[1] "ColName"    "New test defiend"  "FirstWord!G54:Y23 (matched)" "test:New"
```

Here, we wrap the pattern `Upper-case letter(s)digit(s):Upper-case letter(s)digit(s)` into a capturing group to be able to refer to it using backreference `\\1` in `sub`'s replacement clause; there, we also add the desired "First_Word!" string.

If the pattern should **not** be case-sensitive, just add `(?i)` to the front of the pattern.

Data:

```
txt <- c("ColName","New test defiend","G54:Y23 (matched)","test:New")
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I avoid this row to be matched with this pattern. "AnyWord!"G54:Y23   (AnyWord) can be any string.

Comment: Can you please give a few concrete examples of what you mean?